# Apache unable to access mounted Samba share

Tags: apache-2.2, samba, centos6

I'm running Apache 2.2 on CentOS 6.5, and I'm having problems accessing a Samba share that I've mounted.

My web root is `/var/www/html`, and I've created a folder in the root called `intranet`, and I'm mounting the share to that folder using the following line in fstab:

```
\\remote.server\share\intranet  /var/www/html/intranet  cifs    rw,auto,guest,uid=apache,gid=apache 0 0
```

I'm able to access this share and read/write it as root.  I'm also able to `sudo -u apache` to read and write the share.  As far as I can tell on a system level, the share is mounted exactly as desired.

However, when I try to access the share by going to `http:\\myserver\intranet` I get the following message:

> `You don't have permission to access /intranet/ on this server.`

However, when I `umount intranet`, I'm able to successfully access the plain folder `intranet` with `http:\\myserver\intranet` successfully, which tells me my `httpd.conf` and `.htaccess` is configured correctly.

As far as I can tell, the problem is that, somewhere along the line, some permission isn't translating correctly.  I'm not sure what else I can do to solve this.

**EDIT**:  I realize I didn't say anything, but I also have my httpd.conf and .htaccess files configure to `FollowSymLinks`.  I've successfully tested this by linking a test directory and accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this out.  The problem was SELinux.

The policy `httpd_use_cifs` was set to off.  I was able to see this by running:

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

Then I saw that `httpd_use_cifs --> off`.  All that was left to do was change the policy:

```
setsebool -P httpd_use_cifs on
```

Note:  the `-P` flag writes the policies to disk so they will persist through reboots.  You can omit the -P flag to temporarily test your policy change without committing it to disk.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest thing for me wxas to as a symlink to /var/www/html/
For example ln-s /path/to/share/ linkname.

Comment: If you answer an old question, read prior answers.